# Search in a table based on multiple column value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table, i want to filter data of table based on multiple column value whether I type value of one column or more then one.

i am using this code.

```
ALTER proc usp_GetData
@name varchar(50)= NULL ,
@sector int =NULL,`
`@pocket varchar(50) =NULL ,
@plot int =NULL ,
@locality varchar(50) =NULL
as Select * from m_Details where v_RegName =@name AND n_sector =@sector AND v_pocket=@pocket AND n_plotNo=@plot AND v_locality=@locality
```

i want to replace column value like @name with IS NOT NULL therefore i will get my result.

Answer (score 0):

In your procedure, replace bits like `v_RegName =@name`  with

```
(@name is null or v_RegName = @name)
```